# Stopping a PDF file from opening on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, drag-and-drop

Building a HTML5 drag and drop file uploader.

How can I avoid files being opened for viewing inside the browser?

For example if you drag and drop a PDF file it will open that PDF inside the browser for you to view. Can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior from happening. Something like this worked for me...

HTML:

```
<div id="dropArea" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)" onClick="selectFile(event)"></div>
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileSelectionButton" onChange="fileButtonChange()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
}

function selectFile(e) {
    $('#fileSelectionButton').click();
}
```